# Card Game In unity how to set value and suit on card game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, gameobject

How would i give a value and a suit to the card game object depending on the sprite it has.The sprite is randomised from an array so the the game object will be a different card each time.Thanks

Comment: Can you improve your question to share what have you done so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: You should not be randomizing the sprites as the primary decider on what a card is. You should be randomizing card suits/numbers, and then assign a sprite to that card based on its suit/number. Once you have the metadata for what a card is, grabbing its sprite should be an easy lookup.

Comment: I added that as an answer so we can close this out if it works for you.

Comment: yes it sounds good i will try it out

Answer (score 1):

You should not be randomizing the sprites as the primary decider on what a card is. You should be randomizing card suits/numbers, and then assign a sprite to that card based on its suit/number. Once you have the metadata for what a card is, grabbing its sprite should be an easy lookup.

Comment: depending on which card is chosen ,what is the best technique to use to assign its sprite .Since there is 52 cards using switch or If-ElseIf would be very long.

Comment: If you have some sort of naming convention to your sprites, you could possibly construct a string based on the card suit/number to match a sprite name. Otherwise, you'll need a helper method somewhere where you can pass it a card, and it'll give you back a sprite to use. And that method would basically be the long list of if conditions you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the support and the very fast replies.